# mousePressEvent not binding correctly?

Tags: c++, events, qt, qgraphicsview

To familiarize myself with Qt's graphics view, I'm implementing a simple chess board in Qt. There are no chess pieces, for now.

I use rectangles to represent every tile, so I made the `BoardTile` class (which inherits from `QGraphicsRectItem`) so that I can define a `mousePressEvent`.

Here's a little test code that I associated with the mouse click:

```
void BoardTile::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
    QMessageBox mesg;
    std::stringstream mesgText;
    mesgText << "Clicked tile (" << this->row_id << ", " << this->col_id << ").";
    mesg.setText(QString::fromStdString(mesgText.str()));
    mesg.exec();
}
```

When I click the first tile on the second row, I get the following message:

> Clicked tile (1, 0)

Then, when I click any other tile, I get the exact same message. The contents of the message depends on whichever tile I clicked first. Why is this? Did I bind the `mousePressEvent` incorrectly?

**Full code**
http://www.box.net/shared/4m6nrvuxa4 *(update 1)*

**Update 2**: I noticed that if I put `event->ignore();` after `mesg.exec()`, it works fine. I know it's not a solution (because it will probably lead to all kinds of weird behavior), but I do wanna know why that does work. Does this reveal anything crucial about any possible mistakes I've made in my implementation?

**Update 3**: Someone told me I should try changing `mousePressEvent` to `mouseReleaseEvent`. Oddly enough, that works. As far as I know, the only difference between the two events is that the first is triggered when you press the mouse button and the latter when you release that button. So why does `mouseReleaseEvent` trigger the desired behavior and `mousePressEvent` doesn't?

Comment: How are you binding? Are you manually creating the connection using `connect()`? Or are you allowing Qt to do it be itself in MOC?

Comment: I don't do the binding myself. I just make sure there's a `mousePressEvent` function that will have to be executed when the element is clicked.

Comment: regarding Update 2: `event->ignore()` is basically saying that you want the event to not end at this handler but to possibly propogate(sp?) to another handler (if present). Not sure why this is working as I am unable to see your code as the link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does this work? http://www.pieterdedecker.be/tmp/QtChess2.zip

Answer (score 3):

When you are doing `this->x_id` you are getting the x position of the RECT, not your mouse click. You have to do `event->::pos()` taken from the event. The docs are [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html#pos).

Comment: I know, but `x_id` and `y_id` custom-defined. The 1st tile on the 2nd row has `x_id` 0 and `y_id` 1, and so on. (I just noticed I'm using X and Y incorrectly; I'll correct that later.)

Comment: I updated my code and question. I hope that clears up some confusion about what I did with the `x_id` and `y_id`.

Comment: Are you entirely sure that you're properly setting x_id (row_id) and y_id (col_id) when you initialize the objects? Would it be possible to see more of the code (mostly pertaining to the initialization of your `BoardTile` object

Comment: Regarding this answer, it is relatively easy to use this `event::pos()` function to see which rect you have clicked. Create a list,vector or w/e container you would like of all of the rects. When one is clicked, get the mouse location of the click, and loop through your rects, checking to see if the click is within the top left and bottom right x,y of each rect. One loop solves this issue (without seeing anything else about how its implemented atm, as because I cannot see the source)

Comment: Manually determining which rectangle was clicked sounds kinda defeats the purpose of Qt's events altogether. Here's the weird part: `mouseReleaseEvent` does work properly. Any guesses as to why that works as expected and `mousePressEvent` doesn't?

Comment: your link is dead btw.